# If I have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION already, can I omit ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-permissions

I have a GPS app that already requests `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in the manifest, now I want to add a library (MoPub)  that requires `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

Am I correct in assuming that `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is enough, and I can leave out `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` from my manifest?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission

> Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

In short: yes, you don't need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` if you've already defined `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Comment: +1 but oddly, Google Maps doc recommend to use both: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#specify_app_settings_in_the_application_manifest

Comment: Perhaps for phones that have network capabilities but no GPS?

Comment: @NicklasA. logically, that shouldn't affect the fact that "fine" includes "coarse" - the missing provider will simply be missing.  Also, if it were needed for that case, then I would expect Google docs to say so.

Comment: Update on @alex's comment: Google Maps now explicitly says you only need to request one permission. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location

Answer (score 22):

Depends on your needs.

Permission wise, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` includes `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. However, there is a catch:

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` gives you last-known location which is battery friendly
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#setup
For example, if your app does something like location-based recommendations, last-known location is good enough.
This has a **dependency on Google Play Services**

However, if you need something like live/ real-time location like Pokemon Go, use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
It gives you live/ real-time location. You'll need to use a `LocationListener`
Last time I checked, **this does not require Google Play Services**

Comment: Would this permission be useful for Bluetooth LE scanning?

Comment: @ericn maybe you can help me with location issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917764/gpgga-and-gprmc-sentences-are-not-received-in-onnmeamessage I have very strange behavior when listening for NMEA sentences.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

> On Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, users can request that your app retrieve only approximate location information, even when your app requests the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION runtime permission.
>
> To handle this potential user behavior, don't request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission by itself. Instead, request both the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission and the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in a single runtime request. ***If you try to request only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the system ignores the request on some releases of Android 12***.

Check this url: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request

Answer (score 1):

Difference:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#accuracy
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request

***You need to ask for both permissions.***

> Approximate
> Provides an estimate of the device's location, to within about 1 mile (1.6 km). Your app uses this level of location accuracy when you
> declare the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission but not the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. Precise
> Provides an estimate of the device's location that is as accurate as possible, usually within about 160 feet (50 meters) and sometimes
> as accurate as within 10 feet (a few meters) or better. Your app uses
> this level of location accuracy when you declare the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
>
> If the user grants the approximate location permission, your app only
> has access to approximate location, regardless of which location
> permissions your app declares.
>
> Your app should still work when the user grants only approximate
> location access. If a feature in your app absolutely requires access
> to precise location using the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, you can
> ask the user to allow your app to access precise location. ``

***Then in Android 12 permission changes***

> On Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, users can request that your
> app retrieve only approximate location information, even when your app
> requests the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION runtime permission.
>
> To handle this potential user behavior, don't request the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission by itself. Instead, request both the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission and the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> permission in a single runtime request. If you try to request only
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the system ignores the request on some releases
> of Android 12.